# Persist claims added after user is authenticated by Identity Server

Tags: persistence, identity, access-token, claims-based-identity, identityserver3

Is there a way I can persist my application specific claims added to the identity after it gets authenticated by Identity Server. I don't want to load the claims from database for the user and add everytime I want to access my API.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for these cases is Claims transformation.
You can add more claims to `token` after user authenticated with IdentityServer and redirected to you client.